# Textarea js убрать скролл

Tags: javascript, textarea

у меня не странице есть textarea

Я хочу отправлять сообщения из него при нажатии **Enter** это делает вот такой код:

```js
function Form(){
  let text = document.getElementById("messenter").value;
  $("#messenter").val(' ');
  text = text.trim();
  sendMessage(text);
}
```

Всё работает отлично, но когда я отправляю сообщение и очищаю textarea вот этой строкой:

```
$("#messenter").val(' ');
```

Textarea убирает текст, но переходит уже на другую (вторую) строку. Даже когда я задаю
Css:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Выложите сюда код, который воспроизводит проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подробнее в комментариях к коду

```js
$('#messenter').on('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.key === 'Enter' && $(this).val().trim().length > 0) {
    Form();
    return false; // При нажатие enter вызовите return false, чтобы Enter не ставился в textarea
  }
});

function Form(){
  let text = document.getElementById("messenter").value; // Старайтесь не мешать JS и JQ, замените на $('#messenter').val();
  $("#messenter").val('');
  text = text.trim();
  //sendMessage(text);
  console.info(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="messenter"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, благодарю!